# Media Queries: How to target mobile Desktop Site?

Tags: css, reactjs, mediaquery

I have been working on my website i have used various media queries to work well in every screen size. I'm aware about the media queries for every screen. I have also read this page

**[Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)**

It was very useful. But My question are when i use my website on mobile it working fine **but when i do in Desktop site in Mobile their content is breaking can anyone tell me Media query for that scenario.
Thank you**

I have used this:-
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 700px)--- For Mobile

Other two i used for to get resolve my problem that i asked above :-

- @media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width:767px)
- @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:975px)

I haven't use below 2 media query because after using this they affecting my desktop view.

- @media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
- @media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }

Can anyone tell me how can i resolve the issue.

Comment: Has the head element got something like this in it? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: No, I have n't include that in my head element.

Comment: Well try it and see if it makes a difference, it should do!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good way to provide specific media queries for every screen size,
Here is basic media queries for commonly use for devices:

## Mobile

only screen and (min-width: 360px)

only screen and (min-width: 480px)

## Tablet

only screen and (min-width: 768px)

## Desktop

only screen and (min-width: 992px)

## Huge

only screen and (min-width: 1280px)

Some times i prefer 2  media queries for phone screens
these media queries are enough for all screens if your code structure is good and you are not using extra margin and paddings these are the reasons which affect the media queries.

Comment: Why does this solve the problem of the queries not apparently having an effect on desktop mobile view?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).